# Normalizing the values in a data table using the values stored in another data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to normalize the values in a data table (`dt`) using the baseline values stored in another data table (`dt.base`). Next you have a sample contents of these tables and the code to generate that example:

```
> dt
   Bench Config Part Power
1:     A     10    P   171
2:     A     10    Q   125
3:     A    100    P   139
4:     A    100    Q   109
5:     B     10    P   196
6:     B     10    Q   101
7:     B    100    P   157
8:     B    100    Q   176
> dt.base
   Bench Config Part Power
1:     A   Base    P   187
2:     A   Base    Q   104
3:     B   Base    P   166
4:     B   Base    Q   188
```

Example generation code:

```
set.seed(13)

dt <- data.table(
  Bench = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4)),
  Config = rep(c(10, 10, 100, 100), 2),
  Part = rep(c('P', 'Q'), 4),
  Power = round(runif(8, 100, 200)))

dt.base <- data.table(
  Bench = c(rep('A', 2), rep('B', 2)),
  Config = c('Base', 'Base', 'Base', 'Base'),
  Part = rep(c('P', 'Q'), 2),
  Power = round(runif(4, 100, 200)))
```

The idea would be to divide all the values in `dt` by their corresponding values in `dt.base`. Therefore, the table would become:

```
   Bench Config Part Power
1:     A     10    P   171 / 187
2:     A     10    Q   125 / 104
3:     A    100    P   139 / 187
4:     A    100    Q   109 / 104
5:     B     10    P   196 / 166
6:     B     10    Q   101 / 188
7:     B    100    P   157 / 166
8:     B    100    Q   176 / 188
```

I thought the solution for this was quite straightforward, but I am running into some issues. This is my current attempt:

```
normalize.power <- function(pwr, base.pwr) {
  pwr / base.pwr
}

dt.norm <- dt[,
    Power <- normalize.power(
      .SD, dt.base[Bench == Bench & Config == 'Base' & Part == Part,
                   'Power', with = F]
    ), by = list(Bench, Config, Part)]
```

The problem is that `normalize.pwr` is not receiving a single value in its second parameter (`base.pwr`), but rather a vector containing all the power values in `dt.base`. However, when I directly execute from the command line

```
dt.base[Bench == 'A' & Config == 'Base' & Part == 'P', 'Power', with = F]
```

then I obtain a single power value, as expected.

I would appreciate any help that solves my problem or leads me to the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
setkey(dt, Bench, Part)
setkey(dt.base, Bench, Part)

dt[dt.base, Power := Power / i.Power]
dt
##    Bench Config Part   Power
## 1:     A     10    P 0.91444
## 2:     A    100    P 0.74332
## 3:     A     10    Q 1.20192
## 4:     A    100    Q 1.04808
## 5:     B     10    P 1.18072
## 6:     B    100    P 0.94578
## 7:     B     10    Q 0.53723
## 8:     B    100    Q 0.93617
```

Thanks @Arun for the useful `i.Power` syntax

Comment: +1, Note that you can refer to `power` from `dt.base` as `i.Power` (when they share the same name). So no need for `setnames`.